# Laravel 5.3 Providers Class 'GuzzleHttp\Guzzle\Client' not found

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, ibm-watson

Hi I am trying to use Guzzle with my Laravel 5.3 project.

I used compose require to install it and is in my composer.json `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",`

I am not sure what to put in the providers array in app.php 
I currently have `GuzzleHttp\Guzzle\Client::class,`

On my Php file where I use Guzzle
I have `use GuzzleHttp\Client;`

`$client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/',
        ]);`

Please help as I am getting `FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Guzzle\Client' not found`

Thanks

EDIT

So after reinstalling and removing the line `GuzzleHttp\Guzzle\Client::class` in `app.php` it actually works. Is this bad that I now dont have it in app.php?

Comment: Sounds like the package isn't installed

Comment: Do you have a folder called guzzlehttp in your vendor directory?

Comment: Yes I have a folder called guzzlehttp in Vendor

Answer (score 0):

I think guzzleHttp package not available in vendor.

Follow the below link step to install guzzleHttp package

https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

Answer (score 0):

First check the vendor folder to confirm that `guzzleHttp` package is exist?

Now run below command to resolve and install your dependencies:

```
composer update
```

After this process, hopefully this issue will get resolved!

Comment: Yes there is a folder in the vendor folder called `guzzlehttp` thanks for your help

Comment: I got this error after running compose update `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'GuzzleHttp\Guzzle\Client' not found ` what does this mean